# Space Invaders Type Game, Missiles won't Show Up

Tags: java, graphics

As the title says, my missiles aren't showing up. I'm not sure if it's an input error, or what. Here's what the assignment says:

> BlockquotePart 5: Shooting
>
> The patrol ship will shoot a missile when the up arrow key is pushed.
>   Make class variables patrolMissileX and patrolMissileY. Initialize
>   patrolMissileY to 0. Make a contant PATROL_MISSILE_LENGTH initialized
>   to 10. Write a method: public static void
>   movePatrolMissileAndDraw(Graphics g); that moves the missile and draws
>   it similar to moveEnemyShipAndDraw: Do not draw anything if
>   patrolMissileY is 0. Otherwise, the missile as a vertical line with
>   the stated length and x-position. patrolMissileY is the top of the
>   line. Draw the missile in white, move the missile up 5 pixels, and
>   draw it again in black. If the patrolMissileY is 0 or negative, do not
>   draw the missile in black, but set patrolMissileY to 0.
>
> Call this method before the sleep in the loop.  When the up arrow key
>   is pushed and patrolMissileY is 0, set patrolMissileX to be the center
>   of the patrol ship and set the top of the missile so that its bottom
>   is one pixel above the top of the patrol ship (PATROL_Y). You should
>   only be able to fire one missile at a time and the up arrow should not
>   do anything if a missile is still displayed.

Also, since I keep coming here for every part, any tips for the final part would be appreciated:

> Part 6: Detecting a hit
>
> Make a boolean class variable, hit, initialized to false; Write the
>   method: public static boolean detectHit(); that returns true if the
>   current missile has hit the enemy ship and false otherwise. There is a
>   hit if the top of the missile is inside the enemy ship. For this to
>   happen two thing must be true: the x value of the top of the missile
>   must be between the left and right sides of the enemy the y value of
>   the top of the missile must be between the top and bottom of the
>   enemy. At the end of the loop in startGame, set hit to true if
>   detectHit() returns true. Modify moveEnemyShipAndDraw so that if hit
>   is true, the enemy ship is drawn in black and does not move. In this
>   case, display the message: Enemy ship hit! in green on a line below
>   the patrol ship.  If the enemy ship moves off the screen or time runs
>   out, Display the message: Enemy ship got away! in red on a line below
>   the patrol ship.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Project2 {
  public static final int PATROL_Y = 250;
  public static final int PATROL_SIZE = 20;
  public static int patrolX = 270;  
  public static final int ENEMY_Y = 20;
  public static final int ENEMY_SIZE = 30;
  public static int enemyX = 0;
  public static final int RIGHT_ARROW = 39;
  public static final int LEFT_ARROW = 37;
  public static final int UP_ARROW = 38;
  public static int patrolMissileX = 0;
  public static int patrolMissileY = 0;
  public static final int PATROL_MISSILE_LENGTH = 10;

  //exe starts here
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(300, 300);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics( );
    g.drawString("Project 2 by Garrett Griffin", 10, 15);
    startGame(panel, g);
  }

  //Creates a patrol ship at x = patrolX,y=PATROL_Y, with side PATROL_SIZE in the given color
  public static void drawPatrol(Graphics g, Color c){
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(patrolX, PATROL_Y, PATROL_SIZE, PATROL_SIZE);
  }

  //moveEnemyShipAndDraw: draws the enemy ship first in white, then increment enemyX by 1, then draws the ship in red again.
  public static void moveEnemyShipAndDraw(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g.fillRect(enemyX, ENEMY_Y, ENEMY_SIZE, ENEMY_SIZE);
      enemyX+=1;
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillRect(enemyX, ENEMY_Y, ENEMY_SIZE, ENEMY_SIZE);
      if(enemyX>300) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("The enemy ship got away!", 10, 290);
      }
    }

  //Handles user input: RIGHT_ARROW and LEFT_ARROW moves patrolship by 3 pixels left or right
  public static void handleKeys(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) {
    //Set panel.getKeyCode(); to a variable. Any variable. 
    int i = panel.getKeyCode();
    //keep from going out of bounds on the right side
    if (RIGHT_ARROW==i && patrolX>=280) {
      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g.fillRect(patrolX, PATROL_Y, PATROL_SIZE, PATROL_SIZE);
      patrolX-=3;
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.fillRect(patrolX, PATROL_Y, PATROL_SIZE, PATROL_SIZE);
    } else if (LEFT_ARROW==i && patrolX<=0) {
      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g.fillRect(patrolX, PATROL_Y, PATROL_SIZE, PATROL_SIZE);
      patrolX+=3;
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.fillRect(patrolX, PATROL_Y, PATROL_SIZE, PATROL_SIZE);
      //if RA, move right 3 pixels
    } else if (RIGHT_ARROW==i) {
      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g.fillRect(patrolX, PATROL_Y, PATROL_SIZE, PATROL_SIZE);
      patrolX+=3;
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.fillRect(patrolX, PATROL_Y, PATROL_SIZE, PATROL_SIZE);
      //if LA, move left 3 pixels
    } else if(LEFT_ARROW==i) {
      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g.fillRect(patrolX, PATROL_Y, PATROL_SIZE, PATROL_SIZE);
      patrolX-=3;
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.fillRect(patrolX, PATROL_Y, PATROL_SIZE, PATROL_SIZE);
      //if zero, do nothing
    } else if(i==0) {
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.fillRect(patrolX, PATROL_Y, PATROL_SIZE, PATROL_SIZE);
    }
  }

  //Gets uparrow input from user to create missile. Do not draw anything if patrolMissileY is 0. 
  public static void movePatrolMissileAndDraw(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) {
    int i = panel.getKeyCode();
    if(UP_ARROW==i && patrolMissileY>0){
      patrolMissileX=patrolX;
      patrolMissileY=PATROL_Y;
      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g.drawLine(patrolMissileX, patrolMissileY, PATROL_MISSILE_LENGTH, PATROL_MISSILE_LENGTH);
      patrolMissileY+=5;
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawLine(patrolMissileX, patrolMissileY, PATROL_MISSILE_LENGTH, PATROL_MISSILE_LENGTH);
    }
  }

  public static void startGame(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 270;
    int deltaX = 1;
    int deltaY = -3;
    drawPatrol(g, Color.green);
    for (int time = 0; time <= 1000; time++) {
      moveEnemyShipAndDraw(g);
      handleKeys(panel, g);
      movePatrolMissileAndDraw(panel, g);
      panel.sleep(50);
    }
  }
}
```

DrawingPanel class I'm using:

```
/*
Stuart Reges and Marty Stepp
February 24, 2007
Changes by Tom Bylander in 2010 (no anti-alias, repaint on sleep)
Changes by Tom Bylander in 2012 (track mouse clicks and movement)
Changes by Tom Bylander in 2013 (fix bug in tracking mouse clicks)
Changes by S. Robbins   in 2014 (getters for width and height)
Changes by S. Robbins   in 2014 (addKeyListener added)
Changes by S. Robbins   in 2014 (catch exception on default close so that it works in an applet)
Changes by S. Robbins   in 2015 (buffer key events)
Changes by S. Robbins   in 2015 (show mouse status by default is off)

The DrawingPanel class provides a simple interface for drawing persistent
images using a Graphics object.  An internal BufferedImage object is used
to keep track of what has been drawn.  A client of the class simply
constructs a DrawingPanel of a particular size and then draws on it with
the Graphics object, setting the background color if they so choose.

To ensure that the image is always displayed, a timer calls repaint at
regular intervals.
*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DrawingPanel implements ActionListener {
 private static final String versionMessage = 
    "Drawing Panel version 1.1, January 25, 2015";
 private static final int DELAY = 100;  // delay between repaints in millis
 private static final boolean PRETTY = false;  // true to anti-alias
 private static boolean showStatus = false;
 private static final int MAX_KEY_BUF_SIZE = 10;

 private int width, height;    // dimensions of window frame
 private JFrame frame;         // overall window frame
 private JPanel panel;         // overall drawing surface
 private BufferedImage image;  // remembers drawing commands
 private Graphics2D g2;        // graphics context for painting
 private JLabel statusBar;     // status bar showing mouse position
 private volatile MouseEvent click;     // stores the last mouse click
 private volatile boolean pressed;      // true if the mouse is pressed
 private volatile MouseEvent move;      // stores the position of the mouse
 private ArrayList<KeyInfo> keys;

 // construct a drawing panel of given width and height enclosed in a window
 public DrawingPanel(int width, int height) {
   this.width = width;
   this.height = height;
   keys = new ArrayList<KeyInfo>();
   image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

   statusBar = new JLabel(" ");
   statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
   statusBar.setText(versionMessage);

   panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
   panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
   panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));

   click = null;
   move = null;
   pressed = false;

   // listen to mouse movement
   MouseInputAdapter listener = new MouseInputAdapter() {
     public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       pressed = false;
       move = e;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("moved (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
       pressed = true;
       move = e;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("pressed (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
       pressed = true;
       move = e;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("dragged (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
       click = e;
       pressed = false;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("released (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
//       System.out.println("mouse entered");
       panel.requestFocus();
     }

   };
   panel.addMouseListener(listener);
   panel.addMouseMotionListener(listener);
   new DrawingPanelKeyListener();

   g2 = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
   g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   if (PRETTY) {
     g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
     g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.1f));
   }

   frame = new JFrame("Drawing Panel");
   frame.setResizable(false);
   try {
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // so that this works in an applet
   } catch (Exception e) {}
   frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
   frame.getContentPane().add(statusBar, "South");
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);
   toFront();
   frame.requestFocus();

   // repaint timer so that the screen will update
   new Timer(DELAY, this).start();
 }

 public void showMouseStatus(boolean f) {
   showStatus = f;
 }

 public void addKeyListener(KeyListener listener) {
   panel.addKeyListener(listener);
   panel.requestFocus();
 }

 // used for an internal timer that keeps repainting
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   panel.repaint();
 }

 // obtain the Graphics object to draw on the panel
 public Graphics2D getGraphics() {
   return g2;
 }

 // set the background color of the drawing panel
 public void setBackground(Color c) {
   panel.setBackground(c);
 }

 // show or hide the drawing panel on the screen
 public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
   frame.setVisible(visible);
 }

 // makes the program pause for the given amount of time,
 // allowing for animation
 public void sleep(int millis) {
   panel.repaint();
   try {
     Thread.sleep(millis);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
 }

 // close the drawing panel
 public void close() {
   frame.dispose();
 }

 // makes drawing panel become the frontmost window on the screen
 public void toFront() {
   frame.toFront();
 }

 // return panel width
 public int getWidth() {
    return width;
 }

 // return panel height
 public int getHeight() {
    return height;
 }

 // return the X position of the mouse or -1
 public int getMouseX() {
   if (move == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return move.getX();
   }
 }

 // return the Y position of the mouse or -1
 public int getMouseY() {
   if (move == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return move.getY();
   }
 }

 // return the X position of the last click or -1
 public int getClickX() {
   if (click == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return click.getX();
   }
 }

 // return the Y position of the last click or -1
 public int getClickY() {
   if (click == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return click.getY();
   }
 }

 // return true if a mouse button is pressed
 public boolean mousePressed() {
   return pressed;
 }

 public synchronized int getKeyCode() {
   if (keys.size() == 0)
     return 0;
   return keys.remove(0).keyCode;
 }

  public synchronized char getKeyChar() {
   if (keys.size() == 0)
     return 0;
   return keys.remove(0).keyChar;
 }

  public synchronized int getKeysSize() {
    return keys.size();
  }

 private synchronized void insertKeyData(char c, int code) {
   keys.add(new KeyInfo(c,code));
   if (keys.size() > MAX_KEY_BUF_SIZE) {
     keys.remove(0);
//     System.out.println("Dropped key");
   }
 }

 private class KeyInfo {
   public int keyCode;
   public char keyChar;

   public KeyInfo(char keyChar, int keyCode) {
     this.keyCode = keyCode;
     this.keyChar = keyChar;
   }
 }

 private class DrawingPanelKeyListener implements KeyListener {

   int repeatCount = 0;

   public DrawingPanelKeyListener() {
     panel.addKeyListener(this);
     panel.requestFocus();
   }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
//     System.out.println("key pressed");
     repeatCount++;
     if ((repeatCount == 1) || (getKeysSize() < 2))
        insertKeyData(event.getKeyChar(),event.getKeyCode());
   }

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
   }

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
     repeatCount = 0;
   }

 }

}
```

Thanks for all the help friends. Y'all are invaluable.

Comment: Before coming here, you should first do some debugging. If you've never used a debugger, it's time to start now as they're not that hard to use, and what you learn will be useful for all your future projects.

Comment: I came here because I've been messing with the missile for about an hour or so. The most I've gotten is a weird black bar at a slant across my name in the top right corner... Also, we haven't gone over any debugging yet? I'm not sure when we'll go over that. We've barely gotten to if/else statements.

Comment: You can learn things before your class "goes over them". Check your variables and see what they're doing as your program runs.

Comment: I've just never heard of it before. Is there a certain program I need to download?

Comment: Any IDE such as NetBeans and Eclipse will do it. But shoot, you can query the state of your variables by simply using a "poor man's debugger", but sprinkling temporary println's throughout your program to see what is called when, and what the variables hold. Understanding what your program is doing is key to solving why it's misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

originally you set

```
public static int patrolMissileY = 0;
```

but in

```
public static void movePatrolMissileAndDraw(DrawingPanel panel, Graphics g)
```

you do

```
if(UP_ARROW==i && patrolMissileY>0){
```

it is never going to enter here.